# Cannot ping to VM's hostname?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hostname

I am dumbfounded.  I am trying to ping one of my RHEL VMs with my Windows vSphere client box.  The hostname of this VM is set as, lets say "MyVM".  I verified this with the command `hostname`.  Using `dnsdomainname`, I get `dnsdomainname: Unknown host`.  I don't think that should matter at this point as long as everything is connected on the same network, right?  My vSphere host's hostname is also localhost.  When I try to do `ping MyVM` from my Windows vSphere client box, it says `Ping request could not find host MyVM.  Please check the name and try again.`  However, when I try pinging the IP address of the VM, it is okay.  I think I am missing something critical here.  Can anyone pinpoint what that is?  Thanks! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to make a DNS entry for the Linux host within your DNS server. Otherwise, the Windows box cannot resolve the hostname since it has NO idea what the hostname resolves to.

If you don't have a DNS server add the IP of the RHEL box and the hostname to your hosts file on the Windows machine.